# How do I implement caching in a distributed environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

Currently I have a spring application which processes data stored on a mongo server. The architecture of the application follows a shared nothing approach wherein there is a Master node and 3 slave nodes.

Master node communicates with the slave nodes using rest calls. Once the master node sends a rest call, slave nodes read data from mongo collection, process data and write back to a different collection. Data on mongo is batched i.e if a collection contacts 500 Million records && considering a batchSize of 1 million records the collection would contain 500 batches.

The rest call would communicate include the batchNumber && collection name. Based on this information slave node would fetch the records for that corresponding batch number and process.

The problem I am having is that for each batch I am having to load a dictionary, so if the master sends out 500 rest calls the dictionary is being loaded 500 times. How do I cache this dictionary on the slave node once?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use a distributed cache with a mongodb cache store instead of reinventing the wheel ? something like infinispan or coherence

Comment: are you data distributed or replicated? they are two very different notions

Comment: You may be interested by the JSR 107 also known as JCache API https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107

Comment: Eh-Cache has great Spring support, plus distributed caching. http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/spring-annotations.html